# Wildfly cross site replication for JMS messages

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

We have an internal system running on JBoss 4 that we are looking to upgrade to Wildfly 21, because we can't stay in the past forever.

We have two sites, one active on the east coast and one a warm backup / failover site on the west coast, and each site has two 'standalone' jboss servers in a cluster. We are using embedded messaging currently backed by mysql with mysql replication to keep the backup site in sync in case we need to fail over.

With wildfly the JMS messages aren't stored in the database so our sql replication won't help. I saw that there is ha-policy in Artemis, and relay for cross site communication in jgroups, but I haven't found any documentation linking them together or explaining how to handle this.

So - how do we best effort preserve JMS messages in queue when we fail over to our other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis (the message broker embedded into WildFly which provides the JMS implementation) *does* support JDBC so you can still use MySQL (and its backup replication) if you prefer.

However, performance is much better using the file-based journal implementation. If you use the file-based journal you can replicate the journal data using something like ceph or you can use a ["broker connection"](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html) to mirror your broker(s) to a backup site.

To be clear, I'm not 100% sure WildFly supports configuring a mirror broker connection. That's a relatively new feature in ActiveMQ Artemis and WildFly maintains its own configuration layer for the embedded broker. Furthermore, since WildFly only uses ActiveMQ Artemis to provide a JMS implementation (necessary for Java/Jakarta EE certification) it's not clear that it would *ever* support an advanced feature like mirror broker connections. You would probably be better off configuring a standalone instance of ActiveMQ Artemis as it will provide the most flexibility.

Lastly, it's worth noting that JGroups integration is only for broker *discovery*. It's not used for broker-to-broker communication.

Comment: I had been spending quite a bit of time looking at https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/ha.html and specifically the network based data replication. Are you able to contrast the three options (block level replication, mirror brokers, and ha-policy backups?)

Comment: The documentation you linked is quite old since it's from version `1.0.0` (notice the *1.0.0* in the URL). You should use more up-to-date documentation (like what I linked in my answer). As for contrasting the options...That's something I can do, but that should really be a new question of its own rather than something done in the comments here.

Comment: Despite the 1.0.0 in the URL the page is newer that that as it references Artemis 2.3 "Support for network-based data replication was added in version 2.3". Anyway here is the latest: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html

Comment: Actually that was a mistake in the 1.0.0 documentation. The bit you quoted about "version 2.3" was referencing *HornetQ* 2.3, not Artemis 2.3. ActiveMQ Artemis was based on HornetQ which was donated to the Apache ActiveMQ project. You'll note that this reference was removed in later versions.

Comment: Ok, per your suggestion I opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443784/artemis-mirror-vs-ha-data-replication

Comment: Could  you expand the answer with how to configure a broker connection in wildfly. With standalone artemis it's straight forward, but I don't see anything that looks equivalent in wildfly-messaging-activemq_11_0.xsd

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. It's worth noting that even if you can't configure a mirror broker connection you still have the option to use JDBC or a file-system based solution like ceph.