# Mirror vs. HA Data Replication for disaster recovery

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm looking at the options in ActiveMQ Artemis for data recovery if we lose an entire data centre. We have two data centres, one on the east coast and one on the west coast.

From the documentation and forums I've found four options:

Disk based methods:

1. Block based replication of the data directory between the sites, run Artemis on one site (using Ciphy or DRBD with protocol A). In the event of disaster (or fail over test), stop Artemis on the dead site, and start it on the live site.
2. The same thing but with both Artemis servers active, using an `ha-policy` to indicate the master and the slave using a [shared store](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#shared-store).

Network replication:

3. Like number 2, but with [data replication](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication) enabled in Artemis, so Artemis handles the replication.
4. [Mirror broker connections](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html#mirror).

Our IT team uses / is familiar with MySQL replication, NFS, and rsync for our other services. We are currently handling JMS with a JBoss 4 server replicated over MySQL.

My reaction from reading the documentation is that high availability data replication is the way to go, but is there trade offs I'm not seeing. The only one that mentions DR and cross site is the mirror broker connection, but on the surface it looks like a more difficult to manage version of the same thing?

Our constraints are that we need high performance on the live cluster (on the order of 10s of thousands of messages per second, all small)
We can afford to lose messages (as few as possible preferably) in an emergency fail over. We should not lose messages in a controlled fail over.

We do not want clients in site A connecting to Artemis in site B - we will enable clients on site B in the event of a fail over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the high availability functionality (both shared-store and replication - options #2 & #3) configured via `ha-policy` is designed for use in a *local* data center with high speed, low latency network connections. It is *not* designed for disaster recovery.

The problem specifically with network-based data replication for you is that replication is *synchronous* which means there's a very good chance it will negatively impact performance since every durable message will have to be sent across the country from one data center to the other. Also, if the replicating broker fails then clients will *automatically* fail-over to the backup in the other data center.

Using a solution based on block-storage (e.g. Ceph or DRDB) is viable, but it's really an independent thing outside the control of ActiveMQ Artemis.

The [mirror broker connection](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html#mirror) was designed with the disaster recovery use-case in mind. It is *asynchronous* so it won't have nearly the performance impact of replication, and if the mirroring broker fails clients will not automatically fail-over to the mirror.